Issue with Django CMS Icon Module: Missing Static Path and Extra Class in Generated Markup
I am attempting to utilize the djangocms-icon module to incorporate my own SVG icons into my Django CMS project. Following the documentation, I have successfully added Material Design icons. However, I encounter issues when adding my custom SVG icons.
In my settings.py, I added the following code:
with open('iconset.json') as fh:
    ICONSET = fh.read()

DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS = [
    ('fontawesome5regular', 'far', 'Font Awesome 5 Regular', 'latest'),
    ('fontawesome5solid', 'fas', 'Font Awesome 5 Solid', 'latest'),
    ('fontawesome5brands', 'fab', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands', 'latest'),
    ('materialdesign', 'zmdi', 'Material Design'),
    (ICONSET, 'svg-icon', 'My Icons'),
]

DJANGOCMS_ICON_TEMPLATES = [
    ('svg', 'SVG template'),
]

I have created an iconset.json file at the root of my project:
{
    "svg": true,
    "spritePath": "sprites/icons.svg",
    "iconClass": "svg-icon",
    "iconClassFix": "svg-icon-",
    "icons": [
        "svg-icon-card",
        "svg-icon-card-add"
    ]
}

I have also created my icons.svg file in static/sprites/icons.svg:
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="svg-icon-card">
    <!-- path data -->
  </symbol>
  <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="svg-icon-card-add">
    <!-- path data -->
  </symbol>
</svg>

Additionally, I created templates/djangocms_icon/svg/icon.html:
{% load cms_tags static %}
<span class="icon {{ instance.attributes.class }}">
    <svg role="presentation">
        <use xlink:href="{% static 'sprites/icons.svg' %}#{{ instance.icon }}"></use>
    </svg>
</span>

The issue arises in the generated markup. In the icon addition widget inspection, there is a missing /static/ before sprites/icons.svg#svg-icon-card. Additionally, in the page render, there is an extra svg-icon class after the # in the xlink. The generated markup looks like this:
<span class="djangocms-svg-icon svg-icon svg-icon-card">
    <svg role="presentation">
        <use xlink:href="sprites/icons.svg#svg-icon-card"></use>
    </svg>
</span>

There is a missing /static/ before sprites/icons.svg#svg-icon-card.
There also an issue in my rendered page with an extra "svg-icon " after the # in the xlink.
<span class="icon  cms-plugin cms-plugin-3730">
    <svg role="presentation">
        <use xlink:href="/static/sprites/icons.svg#svg-icon svg-icon-card"></use>
    </svg>
</span>

How can I resolve these issues?
I expected my icon to render in both my icon-picker and my rendered page but since the xlink do not find the path, nothing is shown.
